# Multiline UILabel from xib

Tags: ios

In my `awakeFromNib` function, I have:

```
[_descriptionLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[_descriptionLabel setNumberOfLines:10];
[_descriptionLabel sizeToFit];
```

and yet my label looks like this:

[image: UILabel]

I know I'm setting these calls on the right label, because without these lines, the text appears vertically centered rather than aligned at the top. How can I make make my `UILabel` multiline?

I also tried `setNumberOfLines:0`.

**SOLUTION** I had set the width incorrectly in the xib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that the initial width is set correctly. Then it should expand/shrink the height. But still the label won't be aligned to the top, it will be centered in its previous size after a call of `sizeToFit` (in case the new height is smaller than before, otherwise the origin will stay the same).

Comment: After fixing the width, the label actually is aligned to the top.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to set `[_descriptionLabel setNumberOfLines:0];` which set the number of lines to auto.
2. It might be that `sizeToFit` is changing your label width, try to set it to explicit width, or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using AutoLayout, you need to measure text in code:

```
CGRect frame = _descriptionLabel.frame;
CGSize size = [_descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:_descriptionLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, FLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:_descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode];
frame.size.height = MIN(MAX(size.height, frame.size.height), MAX_ALLOWED_HEIGHT);
_descriptionLabel.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `awakeFromNib` is in the right place. If it's in the view controller, it won't work. If it's in the implementation of a custom label, it should get called and that code should work:

```
@interface TestLabel : UILabel
@end

@implementation TestLabel

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [self setNumberOfLines:10];
    [self sizeToFit];
    NSLog(@"Label: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
}

@end
```

Also, it's easier to set `numberOfLines` to `0`, which means "any number of lines". And you shouldn't need to set `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`, since that's the default.

If you want to keep the code in the view controller, you can move it to `viewDidLoad`, which is the best place to do this kind of setup.

Comment: The `awakeFromNib` code is in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Yes, I tried `setNumberOfLines:0`.